# Drawing canvas depth objects

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

How can I have an array of objects in different depths and draw them in iso projection using canvas/jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML5 Canvas has no support for z-buffering, so you are responsible for drawing the objects in the right order, starting with the one furthest away from the viewer and ending with the one closest to the viewer.

You can do this by simply sorting the array with a comparator function which tells which one of two objects is "deeper". Here is an example which sorts the objects by simply comparing a field `z`. Depending on your exact use-case determining which one is deeper than another might be less straight-forward.

```
function object_compare(obj1, obj2) {
     if (obj1.z == obj2.z) return 0;
     if (obj1.z > obj2.z) {
         return 1;
     } else {
         return -1;
     }
}
array.sort(compare_function);
```

Here are some questions on gamedev.stackexchange.com which could also be interesting to you:

- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48710/is-it-good-to-sort-objects-list-before-every-rendering
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47388/best-technique-for-drawing-isometric-tiles
- https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/48423/basic-isometric-projection-in-javascript